# Trigonometric identity via complex exponential

Tags: complex-numbers

> Noting that
>   $$\text{Re}[z_1z_2] = \text{Re}[z_1]\text{Re}[z_2]-\text{Im}[z_1]\text{Im}[z_2],$$
>   how can
>   $$\cos(\alpha+\beta) = \text{Re}\left[e^{j(\alpha+\beta)}\right]$$
>   be expressed? Give the final answer in a simple form, without complex-valued functions.

[Source.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02HV7.png)

and here is my attempt:

> We know that 
>   $$\cos(\alpha+\beta) = \cos(\alpha)\cos(\beta)-\sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta).$$
>   So taking the real part of the cosine function gives
>   $$\text{Re}\left[\cos(\alpha)\right]\text{Re}[\cos(\beta)]-\text{Im}[\sin(\alpha)]\text{Im}[\sin(\beta)].$$
>
> Now we use Euler's formula to convert sin and cosine to complex exponentials
>   \begin{align*}
> \cos x &= \text{Re}\{e^{ix}\} = \frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}\\
> \sin x &= \text{Im}\{e^{ix}\} = \frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}
> \end{align*}
>   $$ = \left[\frac{e^{j\alpha}+e^{-j\alpha}}{2}\right]\left[\frac{e^{j\beta}+e^{-j\beta}}{2}\right]-\left[\frac{e^{j\alpha}-e^{-j\alpha}}{2j}\right]\left[\frac{e^{j\beta}-e^{-j\beta}}{2j}\right]$$
>   Now once I do this, I will cancel out some terms, but my final answer is not $e^{\alpha+\beta}$ as it should be.

[Source.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFaQj.png)

Please let me know what it is I am doing wrong.
Thanks

Comment: why vote down? what is the problem buddy ?

Comment: I posted the question, and then my attempt, I think my attempt considered as the work I have done !

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation would be one link under that "help" option in the top row that may be useful. http://math.stackexchange.com/help is a link to the general help stuff. Posting the "enter image description here" for your images is a bit sloppy you do realize right?

Comment: For future reference, format your posts. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

You know that:
$$
\cos (\alpha+\beta)=\mbox{Re}\left[e^{i(\alpha+\beta)}\right]=\mbox{Re}\left[e^{i\alpha}e^{i\beta}\right]
$$
Now use the given rule for the real part of a product and you have done.

---

From your rule you have:
$$
\mbox{Re}\left[e^{i\alpha}e^{i\beta}\right]=\mbox{Re}\left[e^{i\alpha}\right]\mbox{Re}\left[e^{i\beta}\right]-\mbox{Im}\left[e^{i\alpha}\right]\mbox{Im}\left[e^{i\beta}\right]
$$
and: $\mbox{Re}\left[e^{i\alpha}\right]=\cos \alpha$, $\mbox{Im}\left[e^{i\alpha}\right]=\sin \alpha$, $\mbox{Re}\left[e^{i\beta}\right]=\cos \beta$, $\mbox{Im}\left[e^{i\beta}\right]=\sin \beta$

Comment: you mean apply this to the last line I wrote ( long complex exponential equations) ?

Comment: I've added to my answer. I hope it's useful :)